# Python: resolve undefined class methods dynamically at runtime and react upon them. Is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let’s say we have class ‚Foo’, would it be possible to resolve undefined method calls or variables on instances of the class and react upon them?

Purpose is to implement a rules engine with a simple distraction-free syntax and allow e.g. `f.sales` instead of `f[‘sales’]`.

```
class Foo:
   …some magic code

   def unkown_method_calls_arrive_here(func):
      return f“you‘ve called {func.__name__}.“

   def unkown_variable_references_arrive_here(var):
      return f“you‘ve called {var.__name__}.“

f = Foo()
# Important the ‚bar’ method is not defined in Foo
print(f.bar)

>>> you‘ve called bar
```

If a generic implementation would not be possible, would it maybe possible to utilize a decorator for such proposes? e.g.:

```
@some_magic_decorator(…)
def func():
   f = Foo()
   print(f.bar)

func()

>>> you‘ve called bar
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `__getattr__` special method was designed for this.  It gets called any time a member lookup is not found.

```
C:\tmp>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 1
...         self.b = 2
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print("You asked for", name)
...         return None
...
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.a
1
>>> a.b
2
>>> a.c
You asked for c
>>>
```

Comment: Perfect! That‘s exactly what I was locking for!